# ASP.NET MVC2 - Isolate subfolder for using PHP

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to have domain.com using asp.net mvc2 technology and domain.com/blog would use php. Is it possible to do this on server and to isolate this folder to use php? I know that it is much easier with subdomain (blog.domain.com) but I'm interested in subfolder solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subfolders shouldn't be an issue. IIS will check for an existing file/folder before it gets to MVC, so placing a /blog folder with your content in should work just fine.  The thing to be wary of is if you want to use /blog in any of your routes, as these will fail because of the existing /blog folder, likely resulting in a 404.

If you are finding that it is not working for any reason, try registering an ignored route:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("blog/{*pathInfo}");
```

That will stop MVC from processing any urls with blog/ in it.

Comment: But is it possible that /blog folder is using PHP and how to do that if possible? 
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference really, as long as you have PHP installed.